# Prime number theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following problem.

> Find the proportion of prime numbers among positive integers up to and including with 500 decimal digits.

I do not have problem with math; the problem is that I do not understand what the problem is asking due to my english. Is my interpretation correct that question is asking?

> Find the proportion of prime numbers among positive integers between $1$ digits and $500$ digits (including both bounds)

Comment: Find the proportion of prime numbers in the interval $[1,x]$, where $x$ has $500$ decimal digits. Answer: $\pi(x)=Li(x)+O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So $x$ is the last number with $500$ decimal digits? ($x+1$ has $501$ digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation looks fine. The exact answer is

$$\pi(10^{500})\over10^{500}-1$$

(You could also write $\pi(10^{500}-1)$ in the numerator, but you don't need to, since $10^{500}$ is clearly not prime.) To check that this is correct, consider the easier example where you want the proportion up to and including $2$ digits, which means the one- and two-digit numbers $1$ to $99$, where the exact answer is

$${\pi(10^2)\over10^2-1}={\pi(100)\over99}={25\over99}$$

If an *approximate* answer is desired, the Prime Number Theorem tells you

$${\pi(10^{500})\over10^{500}-1}\approx{1\over\ln(10^{500})}={1\over500\ln10}\approx.000868589$$